# How to convert .mp4 file to .ts using ffmpeg in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, ffmpeg

I want to convert a `.mp4` file into a `.ts` file programmatically.  I searched and found out that I can use [ffmpeg](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script) library for that, which I have never used before.

I have also successfully imported  this library to my project, but I am not able to figure out how I can convert `.mp4` file into `.ts`. I looked it over and I found commands like:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -an -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list test.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -flags -global_header stream%05d.ts
```

But how can I use this in my iOS project? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need API documentation: http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/index.html

Comment: Hello Wain, i checked this documentation but i didn't get any thing which helps me. Is there any thing else that i should check for this?

Comment: See [here](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav*).

Answer (score 2):

Add `ffmpeg` library in your class. I prefer to use the ffmpeg wrapper class in cocoapods.

```
pod 'FFmpegWrapper', '~> 1.0'
```

Install the pod and use the following codes to convert the mp4 file to ts.

```
FFmpegWrapper *wrapper = [[FFmpegWrapper alloc] init];
[wrapper convertInputPath:inputFilePath outputPath:outputFilePath options:nil progressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, uint64_t totalBytesRead, uint64_t totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    } completionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        success?NSLog(@"Success...."):NSLog(@"Error : %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }];
```

inputFilePath  : bundle path for the mp4 video file
outputFilePath : NSDocumentDirectory path in which you can save the .ts files